# Setting tags across all AWS resources using Datadog

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, tags, datadog

We are using Datadog, integrated with AWS, now we have some existing tagging for all AWS resources(not uniform). To make it more feasible/to aggragate data points in Datadog, I wanted to add new tags to all AWS resources across cross/multiple AWS accounts. We are deploying using Terraform. One way could be making tags mandatory across all resources with module or I can use Terratest/Sentinel tfplan. Basically, there are ways we can do using AWS/Terraform. My question is, can we do it using Datadog Agent itself? (maybe in /etc/datadog-agent.yaml)
What solution would be better in longer run? (for complex AWS arch)

Comment: Why do you want to do it using Datadog? Datadog is for data, not for managing AWS infrastructure. Go with Terraform.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Of course, I don't want to manage AWS infra using Datadog. But, tagging plays crucial role in Datadog, so I am trying to explore/know more about the options here.